# Как применить разные Middlewares для одного роута?

Tags: laravel

Есть роут

```
Route::get('articles', 'ArticleController@index')->name('articles.index');
```

Есть две роли пользователя. Writer и Admin.

Для каждой роли существует группа мидлварей, определенных в Kernel.

Мне нужно, чтобы для каждой роли загружался свой список мидлварей.

Если бы я делал разные маршруты, я бы просто дописал к роуту

```
->middleware('forWriter')
```

И проблем нет. Но у меня 1 маршрут. И как быть? Как запустить разные группы мидлварей для одного роута или какой есть параллельный способ проверить запрос для разных ролей при одном маршруте?

Answer (score 0):

Не вижу проблем. Просто сделайте так к примеру:

```
Route::get('articles', 'ArticleController@index')
->name('articles.index')
->middleware(['forWriter', 'forAdmin']);
```

Далее в самих middleware у вас всегда известно кто на входе пришёл. Например:

```
//forWriter 1

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->user()->isWriter()) {
        // проверяете доступы для роли Writer иначе просто пропускаете!
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Так же вторую группу, только для админа! в результате применится тот посредник который необходим определённой роли!

То что в каждом middleware из группы нужно сделать проверку, это ничего страшного. Либо сделайте какой-нибудь хелпер, чтобы избежать дубля кода и вызывайте его в middleware

Comment: Во-первых до forAdmin в вашем примере не дойдет. Т.к. мидлварь forWriter его не пропустит. Во-вторых forAdmin и forWriter - это не мидлвари. Это группы мидлварей из kernel.
Да можно сделать мидлварь для проверки роли. Но как тогда запустить группы мидлварей forAdmin и forWriter из этой мидлвари?

Comment: @Alex почему не дойдет? всё дойдет. Читайте внимательней я написал //forWriter 1. Что значит 1 миддлвер из группы! данную строку (блок if) надо проверять во всех! Т.е. в миддлверах writer. Если пользователь не writer, просто next вызывайте, иначе проверяйте ваши доступы. тем самым если пользователь admin он пропустит все миддлверы которые указаны в forWriter. и наоборот!

Comment: @Alex ну а в посредниках админа надо isAdmin соответственно проверять

Comment: Мидлвари из групп forWriter и forAdmin участвуют во многих других группах, где проверка роли не требуется. А значит сделает эти мидлвари нерабочими для многих роутов. Также роли это ManyToMany связь с таблицей roles. На каждой мидлвари он будет дергать бд (т.е. 10 одинаковых запросов). Тогда проще вынести код из мидлварей в классы и для указанного роута делать проверку из контроллера с помощью класса, а не мидлвари. Но это тоже костыль и трудоемкое решение.

Comment: @Alex А на каком основании посредники не относящиеся к группе forWriter делают в нём?? Такого делать нельзя. Вы говорите forWriter значит всё что внутри должно использоваться для него не иначе!! все общие посредники не относящиеся к конкретной роли выносятся в отдельную группу! это раз,  а как без проверки роли Вы собираетесь определять что это writer? это 2. по поводу 10 запросов, в оф документации они используют именно так, передают роль и сверяют. сохраняйте в кэш роль пользователя и в последнем мидлвер удаляйте из него после проверки. тем самым будет 1 запрос на всём этапе проверки.

Comment: @Alex если умные люди гуру laravel, дадут решение более уникальное, то супер. Все мы ошибаемся, я предлагаю сделать так Вам.

Comment: Вы предлагаете добавить ко всем посредникам одинаковое действие, которое они не должны делать – проверять роли. Если проверять роли через посредника, то через checkRole, как в доках. Хотя я проверяю с помощью политик в контроллерах. Все посредники из группы forWriter относятся к группе forWriter. Также принадлежат другим группам. Т.к. это просто набор мидлварей, которые к ролям вообще никак не относятся. Они каждый выполняют свою функцию для которой созданы. А не для проверки ролей. Посмотрите пример из доков

Comment: 'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'auth:api',
    ],

Предлагаете throttle и auth более нигде кроме api не использовать, раз они в этой группе?